# jQuery confirm popping up multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems with this confirm box popping up multiple times. I only confirm after a certain button is pressed. If I only click on that button this should only ask once for that button but it's asking me once for every button of that class.

Any ideas why this is looping if I'm only firing this condition when a user clicks on a specific button?

```
$(".TweetNow").each(function () {    
    $(this).click(function TweetThis() {

        var identify = $(this).attr('id');
        var prestart = identify.indexOf('_');
        var start = prestart + 1;
        var end = identify.length;
        var position = identify.substr(start, end);

        var message = $("#Tweet_" + position).val();
        var site = $("#SiteLabel").text();

        if (message != '') {
            var trend = $("#Topic_" + position).text();
            var website = $("#SiteLabel").text();
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to tweet the following message:\n" + message + " ?")) {
                PageMethods.TweetThis(message, site, trend, website);
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using .each here?

Comment: It's because you are using .each with a class type selector. It will run that function for every element that matches your selector.

Comment: @Zack that shouldn't matter though, he's using `this` inside, resulting on a single click event being bound to each element.

Comment: My guess is you are calling this code more than once...

Comment: I'm using an asp repeater so I use the .each to traverse every element with that specified class and using the condition that if any one of those elements with class TweetNow is pressed execute the rest of the code. Since I can't specify an ID using the click right off the bat I need to find which one was clicked.

Comment: What does `PageMethods.TweetThis` do ? can you show the code ?

Comment: `PageMethods.TweetThis` just uses TweetSharp to post a tweet to a certain account. It doesn't return anything just tweets a message, saves the message to my database, and then just continues the rest of the code. There shouldn't be a reason why my code behind would be causing this.

Comment: Does clicking `Cancel` in your confirm message also trigger the loop ?

Comment: So for some reason without changing anything the error seems to have disappeared. I've gone ahead and tried out the solution provided by @Satpal and it still functions correctly. Fairly new to this community so is it fair to accept the solution as the proper answer since it didn't cause any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as

```
$(".TweetNow").click(function() {
    var identify = $(this).attr('id');
    //Rest of code
});
```

Instead of

```
$(".TweetNow").each(function () {    
    $(this).click(function TweetThis() {

    });
});
```